# Reading lines from a file using bufferedreader identifying specific lines

Tags: java, algorithm, bufferedwriter

My scenario is like read a file and replace few words in it and save it as a new file.
But the challenge here is if the file which is being read has 5 lines. if loop count is 3. While replacing and writing it into a new file.

First line should come once(header of the file) Last line should come once(footer of the file) in between lines should be repeated n no of times and should be written in the new file.

Say my loop count is 3. The base file from which I am reading has 5 lines then my output file should have 10 lines.
ie . First line header once, the next three lines to be repeated 3 times(loop) and the last line once (footer).

I have tried a bit, but could achieve it completely. I have attached my code as well

code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
File file = new File(foldername);
                file.createNewFile();


                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                        foldername + "/" + solfilename, true));
                BufferedWriter bsftp = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                        "c:/ToolSOlFile/" + solfilename, true));
try {
                    String verify, putData = null;

                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/ToolSOlFile/Templates/"
                            + template[i]);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    while ((verify = br.readLine()) != null) {
if (verify != null) { 
putData = verify.replace("YYYYMMDD", yyyymmdd);
                            putData = putData.replace("DD", duration);

                            putData = putData.replace("IIIIIIIIIIIIIII", imsi);

                            putData = putData.replace("HHMMSS", startTime);
                            putData = putData.replace("hhmmss", endTime);
                            putData = putData.replace("XXXXXXXXX", msisdn);
                            putData = putData.replace("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
                                    processor.returnTemplateName(template[i]));
bw.append(putData + "\n");
                            bsftp.append(putData + "\n");
        }
                    }

                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();

                    bsftp.flush();
                    bsftp.close();
                    br.close();
startTime = findUpdatedStartTime(startTime);
} catch (IOException e) {
                    log.info("Catching Error @ createBulkSolFile");
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }

            }

}
```

Here wat happens in my code is, Entire file gets written based on the loop, nut i want only the middle lines excluding first and last line of the file.
First and last line to be written once and remaining should be iterated based on the loop.

Comment: Please, learn how to manage your `Reader`s and `Writer`s so as not to leave them open and consuming resources if something goes wrong. See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: okay, but how to iterate those lines in the middle ?